# Time differences between Release and Debug builds

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-construction, time, release

My program is supposed to trigger an event every 180 seconds.

```
mFoodSpawnTime += dt;
if (mFoodSpawnTime > mFoodSpawnCycleLength)
{
       ..... etc;
}
```

mFoodSpawnCycleLength = 180.0f, and mFoodSpawnTime is another float that accrues time every loop.

My problem is that if mFoodSpawnCycleLength is around 180.0f, then on a release build it never seems to arrive, taking up to 10 minutes for mFoodSpawnTime to be > than mFoodSpawnCycleLength! I have timed the debug build and it does execute the loop after the 180 seconds, and I have validated using a stopwatch. Back to the release build: as long as the mFoodSpawnCycleLength isn't near 180.0f it also matches the stopwatch and executes the code. I once set it to 120.0f and when it executed the stopwatch read 2min 30sec. There is no #ifdef DEBUG code that could be causing this.
So what I'm saying is: the closer to 180.0f the mFoodSpawnCycleLength gets, the less precise the time becomes, but only on the release build!

I just now printed out mFoodSpawnTime and when my clock read 3 min, its time was only around 160s, and I found that as the timer approaches 150 seconds the time incrementation just slows to a halt. I tracked the dt in each loop and it doesn't seem to be any different than in the beginning.

Could this all be caused by an intrusive compiler optimization?
A 32-bit floating point error?
I'll continue to look into this, but any help is appreciated.

I'm still learning so I'm using a DirectX Book.
I use the time code from a demo the book provided:

```
int D3DApp::run()
{
MSG  msg;
msg.message = WM_NULL;

__int64 cntsPerSec = 0;
QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER*)&cntsPerSec);
float secsPerCnt = 1.0f / (float)cntsPerSec;

__int64 prevTimeStamp = 0;
QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&prevTimeStamp);

while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    // If there are Window messages then process them.
    if(PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ))
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    // Otherwise, do animation/game stuff.
    else
    {   

        if( mTimeReset )
        {
            QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&prevTimeStamp);
            mTimeReset = false;
        }

        if( !isDeviceLost() )
        {
            static float frameLimit = 0.0f;
            __int64 currTimeStamp = 0;
            QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&currTimeStamp);
            float dt = (currTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp)*secsPerCnt;

            if (dt > 2.0f) dt = 0.0f;

            frameLimit +=dt;

            updateScene(dt);
            if (frameLimit > 0.0167f)
            {
                drawScene();
                frameLimit = 0.0f;
            }

            // Prepare for next iteration: The current time stamp 
            // the previous time stamp for the next iteration.
            prevTimeStamp = currTimeStamp;
                    }
         }
    }
return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: How often is this conditional evaluated?  i.e. how often does it go round this loop?

Comment: And `dt` is 'delta time' - the difference in seconds between this iteration and the last?

Comment: Yes, it is the change of time.

Comment: Without seeing the actual timing code, I will say that timing using `float` values that "accrues time every loop" is not going to be very reliable.  I would suggest using a separate timer thread that you can guarantee with some accuracy (~20ms -- good enough if you're profiling with a stopwatch).

Note that various threading models that are available will be dependent on the target system (Windows, linux, etc.).

Comment: I think we need to see more code - there must be a bug there somewhere; I really doubt it's the compiler optimisation.

Comment: Release builds run faster, if each "loop" happen fast enough, it may be adding 0.0000 to `mFoodSpawnTime` some (most?) loops.  Debugs are slower, so they don't add 0s, so they are more accurate.  Maybe.

Comment: How is the delta time calculated?

Comment: It uses QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER*)&currTimeStamp); against a previous timestamp. It multiplies that by counts of the cpu per second.

Comment: What is the type of `currTimeStamp`?  Suggest using an actual `LARGE_INTEGER` or `__int64`

Comment: Errr, no - we need to see more code to give us the context in which this conditional is evaluated.

Comment: Why `if (dt > 2.0f) dt = 0.0f;` ?

Comment: The food code where the problem occurs is inside of updateScene(dt);

Comment: `if (dt > 2.0f) dt = 0.0f;`?  Why?

Comment: That way if my computer freezes what's happening on screen doesn't jump all over the place because of a large dt. I added that in along with the frameLimit stuff.

Comment: But that will ensure that the delta time is `0` in some cases.  Given that, I cannot assume that it is ever NOT `0`.

Comment: This highlights on issue of using loops to calculate time.  You loop resets the "previous" timestamp in the loop.  If any iteration through the loop can take a `0` time delta, then ALL iterations through the loop can take a `0` time detla, ensuring effectively that your stop condition will never be met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try using double rather than float here. The performance difference in this case will be minimal, and I suspect you may be hitting a problem where you are adding a very small number to a big number - leaving the floating point value of the big number unchanged.

Floats only give you around six digits of precision. If the performance counter period is of the order of ns then you will start to hit problems when frameLimit reaches a few ms.

Debug mode will tend to run slower, resulting in larger increments, which may be why you don't see the problem there.

Comment: I just included the updateScene(dt); under the if (frameLimit...) statement, and changed updateScene(dt); to updateScene(frameLimit); and now it works perfectly. Thanks though for helping me find out why it was happening!